# Does a Pakistani citizen need a visa to visit Jeju Island?

Tags: pakistani-citizens, jeju

I am from Pakistan and our Karachi consulate said to me that we need South Korea visa to visit Jeju Island, do we?

Comment: It is literally the consulate's job to know these things about their own country. Why don't you believe them and why would you believe random people on the internet instead?

Answer (score 7):

You will need a visa.

> Special entry arrangements for Jeju Island is denied to nationals of
>   the following 24 countries:
>
> Iran, Sudan, Syria, Macedonia, Cuba, Kosovo, Palestine, Afghanistan,
>   Iraq, Ghana, Nigeria, Yemen, Egypt, Gambia, Senegal, Bangladesh,
>   Kyrgyz, **Pakistan**, Somalia, Uzbekistan, Nepal, Cameroon, Sri Lanka,
>   Myanmar

[South Korean Embassy in Malaysia](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/my-en/brd/m_1914/view.do?seq=761537&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1)

You will need a Tourist / Transit (General) B-2-1 visa. You can apply [apply here](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10201).

Comment: As a quick clarification, then according to the page linked in this answer then nationals of other countries may visit Jeju Island without a visa for up to 30 days for transit or tourism, even if they would normally require a visa to visit South Korea.

Comment: https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRV/TV_ENG_2_1.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Pakistani nationals now need a South Korean tourist  visa to visit Jeju island. Last year up to April 2018, this was not the case and I was lucky enough to have this beautiful island in January 2018.